# Trying to print simple text program but will not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just trying to have a .py open and print on black console this quotation. Is input () the same as `system("PAUSE")` in C++?

```py
print(“Quote: If people do not believe that mathematics is simple, it's")
print("       only because they do not realize how complicated life is.”)
print("By: John von Neumann")
input()
```

Thanks I'm really trying to get this to work!

Here is output:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate untitled-1.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 4, in <module>
Syntax Error: print (“Quote: If people do not believe that mathematics is simple, it's): None, line 415
```

Comment: So then what does it currently do?

Comment: There's nothing particularly C++ in `system()` -- if anything, it's pure C, but it also exists in `awk`, Perl, etc -- and anyway, like the name implies, it's system-dependent. `PAUSE` must be referring to the MS-DOS command which prompts for a keypress, yes?

Comment: much better than before, however, program still flashes...?

Answer (score 2):

`input()` should work, so it could be the broken quote character from a copy and paste which is giving you an error.  Try changing those `”` into `"`, or better yet use a multiline string with `"""triple quotes"""`.